# How to debug JSPs in JBoss 7.1.x?

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, jboss

Debugging JSPs in JBoss 7.1.3 (not EAP) doesn't work. All breakpoints in JSPs are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config file *standalone.xml* set the *smap* property in the *jsp-configuration* element to the value *false*:

```
<jsp-configuration smap="false" .../>
```

EAP 6.1.0.Alpha (7.2.0.Final) and JBoss 7.1.3 Final (EAP) are not affected.

See also:

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4871
- https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/jsp.html